# How do I set a Replit database key to be the same as a variable?

Tags: python, database, discord, discord.py, replit

I'm making a Discord bot where you set a mute role and it stores that mute role in the Replit database to be used later on with the `mute` command. Here's what I have so far for it:

```py
@client.command()
async def muterole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
  db[f"{ctx.guild.id}_role"] = "role"
  print(db[f"{ctx.guild.id}_role"])
  await ctx.reply("Muterole set!")

@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles):
    ctx.reply("Error: Missing permission `Manage Roles`")
    return
  await member.add_roles(db[f"{ctx.guild.id}_role"])
  await ctx.reply("User successfully muted!")
```

Because I have to set the value for the key as a string value, I can't make the value of the key the actual role's name and it just ends up being literally named `role` instead of the actual role's name which means that when I try to mute someone it can't find the role. How would I be able to set a Replit database key to be the same as the `role` argument when running the command with my bot?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the role id instead. Then you can fetch the role from the guild using the guild id.

`db[f"{ctx.guild.id}_role"] = role.id`
Storing role id.

```py
role = ctx.guild.get_role(db[f"{ctx.guild.id}_role"])

await member.add_roles(role)
```